# Find a Lyapunov function and prove that an almost linear closed-loop system is stable

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I would like to find a Lyapunov function and prove the following closed-loop system is stable:

$\dot{x}=(A-BK)x+(z(u)+\epsilon)$,

where a function of control input $z(u)$ satisfies $\|z\| < \rho \|x\|$ with $\rho$ being a positive small constant, $K$ is an optimal feedback gain from LQR, and $\epsilon$ is small perturbation. You can see this system as an almost linear system, which has small nonlinear disturbance.

Here's my solution (but it fails to achieve to show $x$ converges). I would be very happy if you give me any advice or exhibit another solution:

Overall, I'm going to prove the stability by defining a Lyapunov function $V=x^\top P x$ such that the time-derivative is upper bounded by $V$ itself. Then I can apply [the Comparison lemma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFxmrxBbQug) to the inequality to demonstrate $\lim_{t \to \infty}\|x\|$ converges to an error ball. Note that $P$ is positive semi-definite from the Riccati equation of the LQR. The reason why I use the Comparison lemma is just because I learn this lemma in this semester. Of course, you do not have to use this lemma.

Proof:

$\dot{V} =\dot{x}^\top P x + x^\top P \dot{x}$

$=x^\top(A-BK)^\top P x + x^\top P(A-BK)x+2x^\top P(z+\epsilon) $

Since the first and second terms come from the Riccati equation, we can rewrite the sum using weights $R, Q$ as follows ([watch this video if you do not understand this formulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Y_6-VLi3o)),

$=x^\top(-Q-K^\top R K) x +2x^\top P(z+\epsilon) \cdots$ (i).

To apply the Comparison lemma, I make this time-derivative upper bounded by $V$.

Let $w=\Lambda x$ where $\Lambda$ satisfies $P=\Lambda^\top\Lambda$. Then $V=w^\top w= \|w\|^2$, and using the inequality $\|z\| < \rho \|x\|$,$\|\epsilon\|<\epsilon_m$ the time-derivative (i) becomes
$\dot{V} =x^\top(-Q-K^\top R K) x +2x^\top P(z +\epsilon) $

$\leq \lambda_{max}(-Q-K^\top R K)\|x\|^2+2\|x^\top P\|(\rho\|x\|+\epsilon_{m})$

$\leq \lambda_{max}(-Q-K^\top R K)\|\Lambda^{-1}w \|^2+2\|w^\top \Lambda\|(\rho\|\Lambda^{-1}w\|+\epsilon_{m})$

$\leq \lambda_{max}(-Q-K^\top R K)\sigma(\Lambda^{-1})^2\|w \|^2+2\sigma(\Lambda)(\rho\sigma(\Lambda^{-1})\|w \|^2+\epsilon_m\|w \|) \cdots$ (ii),

where $\sigma(\cdot)$ denotes the
maximum singular value, and $\lambda_{max}(-Q-K^\top R K)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of the negative semi-definite (later it is denoted only as $\lambda$).

Now we have the following inequality

$\dot{V}\leq \sigma(\Lambda^{-1})^2(\lambda +2\sigma(\Lambda)\frac{\rho}{ \sigma(\Lambda^{-1}) })\|w \|^2+2\sigma(\Lambda)\epsilon_{m}\|w \|$

$\rightarrow$
$\dot{V} \leq \alpha V+2\beta\sqrt{V} \cdots$ (iii)

where $\alpha=\sigma(\Lambda^{-1})^2(\lambda +2\sigma(\Lambda)\frac{\rho}{ \sigma(\Lambda^{-1}) })$, and $\beta=\sigma(\Lambda)\epsilon_{m} $. Finally, we can apply the Comparison lemma to (iii) by defining $W=\sqrt{V}, \dot{W}=\dot{V}/2\sqrt{V}$ to get

$2\sqrt{V}\dot{W} \leq \alpha WW+ 2\beta \sqrt{V}$

$\rightarrow$$\dot{W} \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}W+\beta \cdots$ (iv)

By comparison lemma, the inequality (iv) boils down to,

$W(t) \leq W_{0}\exp(\frac{\alpha}{2}(t-t_{0}))-\frac{2\beta}{\alpha}$

Thus, when $\lambda +\sigma(\Lambda)\frac{\rho}{ \sigma(\Lambda^{-1}) }<0$ such that $\frac{\alpha}{2}<0 $, $W(t)=\sqrt{V(t)}=\|w\|$ converges to the error ball $\epsilon_{error}=-\frac{2\beta}{\alpha}=-\frac{2\sigma(\Lambda)\epsilon_{m}}{\sigma(\Lambda^{-1})^2(\lambda +\sigma(\Lambda)\frac{\rho}{ \sigma(\Lambda^{-1}) })}$

Q.E.D

However, as you can see, this whole proof only proves $\|w\|=\|\Lambda x\|$ converge, not $\|x\|$.

How could I fix this process? May the Lyapunov function or using the comparison lemma not be appropriate?
Please give me any advice!
Thank you.

Comment: Your proof assumes the invertibility of $\Lambda$ (you use $\sigma(\Lambda^{-1})$) and therefore assumes the $P$ is invertible. So if $\|\Lambda x\|$ converges, so does $\|x\|.$

Comment: to be clear, the proof has assumed $P$ is positive definite which, as you pointed out, isn't assured.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your notation, i.e. that you use transposition and matrix notation everywhere. Since $\rho$ is scalar and $\Vert x \Vert$ is scalar, $x$ has to be scalar as well and so $\Vert x \Vert = |x|$. So you have a scalar system, is this correct? (not that using transposition in the scalar case is wrong, but I am not sure if this was intended)

Comment: Dear Rollen S. D'Souza,

Thank you for the reply. 

Right, right. If P is positive definite (not semi),  then $\Lambda, P$ are invertible:
$P= UD U^\top=U\sqrt{D} \sqrt{D} U^\top=(\sqrt{D} U^\top)^\top \sqrt{D} U^\top=\Lambda^\top\Lambda$

 and thus $\det P =(\det \Lambda)^2>0$ meaning, $\Lambda, P$ are invertible.

 Is it to be harsh that I assume P is positive definite in this closed-loop system?

 Or do you have another idea to avoid $\Lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: Dear SampleTime, Sorry It was my bad. This is not a scalar system. This is an MIMO system and $\|x\|$ in (i) should've been denoted as $\|x\| e$ with a unit vector $e$

Comment: Dear Rollen S. D'Souza, looking back at a textbook, $P$ can be positive definite. Thus $\Lambda, P$ are invertible and my conclusion seems correct. But I do not understand what you said "So if $\|\Lambda x\|$
 converges, so does $\|x\|$". How is it guaranteed?

Comment: Then you should update the question so that the equations accurately represent the problem you are trying to solve. It is not only (i) which is incorrect, but $\dot{V}$  (and likely the follow up equations) as well, since there no $e$ appears. Also, "unit vector" is not a unique description: in $n$-dimensional space, there are many different unit vectors. Which of those do you mean here? Or are you trying to prove stability for a family of systems (i.e. for all possible unit vectors)? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA You can assume whatever you need for your application. I was merely pointing out the hidden assumption. if $\Lambda$ is invertible, and w enters a ball B then naturally $\Lambda x$ enters a ball $B$. Since invertible linear transforms are homeomorphisms, $x$ enters an open set $\Lambda^{-1} B$.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Thank you. Almost all of problems are solved. Now I have two questions, (i) How should I write the aforementioned statement down to the norm form? Like "Since $\|\Lambda x\|$ converges to the error ball $\epsilon_{error}$, $\| x\| $ to $\|\Lambda^{-1} \| \epsilon_{error}$" ?  (ii) My proof looks messy. Do you have  any idea to improve, such as defining another Lyapunov function or avoiding applying the Comparison lemma etc..?

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you. Okay, I'll check what unit vector meant and then clarify the question.

Comment: @SampleTime I did it!

Comment: @SpaceTAKA I thought with "unit vector" you meant that $e$ is some *constant* unit vector. Having $e$ depending of $x$ makes a big difference because it not only affects the "distribution" of the nonlinear disturbance but changes the nonlinear disturbance itself. You should in any case at least write $e(x)$ to indicate that $e$ is actually a nonlinear function of the state vector and not a constant vector. I added an answer for this new system.

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you. But I’m really sorry that the last modification was my mistake. $e$ was not the unit vector of x. I write the whole system, which I tried not to show, for the sake of readability. I apologize that my manipulation has confused you many times

Comment: @SpaceTAKA The equations still don't make much sense. Since $z(u)$ must be a vector valued function, how can you add a scalar $\epsilon$ to it? And where has the unit vector gone? Or was there never a unit vector? Please: clarify your question and take your time needed to do it conscientiously.

Comment: Thank you, I modified. $\epsilon$ is also a vector, with its norm being upper bounded by $\|\epsilon\| < \epsilon_{m}$. And yes, the last modification made you confused, Sorry: the unit vector did not exist. I think, now the whole question I posted is completed

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Hi, I would like to know how large the resulting error ball radius is. You said $x$ enters $\Lambda^{-1} B$, which means $\|x\|$ converges to $\|\Lambda^{-1} B\|$. But how can you relate $\|B\|$ from the result? $\|B\|$ is not upper bounded $\| \Lambda^{-1} B\| <  \| \Lambda^{-1}\| \|B\| $

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza What I meant is we should somehow upper bound $\|x\|$ to define the error ball, like, $ \lambda_{min}( \Lambda)\|x\| < \|\Lambda x \|=\|w\|  < \|B\|$. Then, we can say $\|x\|$ goes to $\|B\|/\lambda_{min}( \Lambda)$. But in this way, $\Lambda$ has to be positive definite...

Comment: @SampleTime (I've forgotten to inform you of the latest update)

Comment: I suggest you study your question and notation more carefully and come back with a new question that clearly states the dimensions and states the correct system. You have changed the question, and SampleTime's answer was appropriate for that question. In fact, I'm fairly sure their answer worked for the original unedited question as well with a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Okay, thank you for the suggestion and the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the system

$$
\dot{x}=(A-BK)x+\rho(\Vert x\Vert+\epsilon)e(x)
$$

with $e(x)=\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}$. First we can recognize that $\dot{x}$ is undefined for $x=0$. For $x\neq 0$ you get

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=(A-BK)x+\rho(\Vert x\Vert+\epsilon)\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}\\
&=(A-BK)x+\rho I x+\epsilon\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}\\
&=(A-BK + \rho I)x+\epsilon d
\end{align}
$$
with identity matrix $I$ and disturbance
$$
d=\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}
$$
Note that $\Vert d\Vert = 1$ is bounded so your system can be viewed as a linear time invariant (LTI) system with bounded input. As such, it is stable if and only if $(A-BK+\rho I)$ is Hurwitz.

Since stable LTI systems are always input to state stable, $x$ will then converge to some error ball. You can use standard techniques for LTI systems to compute an estimate of that error ball.